# How to retrieve a remote partial in the view in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to have a partial come from a service via a url like so (using ejs):

```
<div>
  <%- remotePartial('http://google.com/?q=hi') %>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: While I understand all the parts of what you're saying, I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want as a contiguous whole. You want to nest one view within another, getting that view from another server?

Comment: @drachenstern There's a number of services that fully render a set of modules (return text/html). I want to include one of those modules on my page. I also want to make sure that the designer has the control of which specific module is included, and which url is used, so this must be done from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to define a dynamicHelper, that fetches the remote template and passes it to the templating engine.

However, this would require asynchronous dynamicHelpers, which are currently not provided. See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/express-js/browse_thread/thread/0a56ac30fd8eae22?fwc=1) on the express user group.

Comment: In the mean time since asynchronous dynamicHelpers aren't supported, you'll need to load the HTML from the remote site ahead of time and then make the HTML available to the template as a local when you call `res.render`